# Store print_r result into a variable as a string or text

Tags: php

If I use `print_`r or `var_dump` it displays the result on the screen, but I want this data to be stored in a variable so that I can write it to a file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Look in the manual on `print_r`, or http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 316, accepted):

```
   $var = print_r($what, true);
```

You must add true into [print_r](http://php.net/manual/function.print-r.php).

Answer (score 13):

What you do while you print or dump? Basically you send your data (result or anything) to Show it on screen. Keep your mind clear that its not saved, it is just displayed, 
To save the data , so a simple thing, just declare a variable and assign the data to it..

for example you are printing some array like this..

```
print_r(myArray);
```

to save this, you just have to add an option , set Return to TRUE and assign it to a variable

```
$myVariable=print_r(myArray, TRUE);
```

if you need some more information, Follow [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

hoping this will help you understanding the concept

Comment: for making it 1k... I should have achieved this quite earlier than today

Answer (score 3):

```
ob_start();
var_dump($someVar);
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

it works.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) also shows a bit more information than either `print_r()` or `var_export()`.