# Array of textboxes in message PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

Here is textboxes I am trying to send with email.
Please help me with the code.The textboxes are dynamic

HTML

```
  Flavor<input class="textbox" type='text' id="fl" name="flav[]" value=""/></label></br>
```

AJAX

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#submit_btn").click(function() {


            var str  = new Array();
            $("input[name='flav[]']").each(function(){
                str.push($(this).val());
            });
            alert(str);
            var proceed = true;
            if(str==""){
                $('input[name=flav]').css('border-color', 'red');
                proceed = false;
            }
            if(proceed)
            {
                //data to be sent to server
                post_data={'userData':str};

                $.post('mail.php', post_data, function(response){

                    //load JSON data from server and output message
                    if(response.type == 'error')
                    {
                        output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    }else{
                        output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                        //reset values in all input fields
                        $('#contact_form input').val('');
                         }

                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }, 'json');

            }
        });

        //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
        $("#contact_form input").keyup(function() {
            $("#contact_form input").css('border-color', '');
            $("#result").slideUp();
        });

    });

</script>
```

PHP

```
   <?php
 if($_POST)
  {
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND         strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    //exit script outputting JSON data
    $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

    die($output);
}

if(!isset($_POST["userData"]))
{
 }

foreach($_POST as $key=> $value)
{
    $message .= $key .":".$value."<br>";
}
 $headers = "From: " . $user_Email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".  $user_Email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject,  $message, $headers);

if(!$sentMail)
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
}
  }
   ?>
```

Kindly help me with this. 
How can I recieve all the values entered via message?

I have edited the code

Comment: What is your error/problem? What's not working? What did you expect? Maybe you should call `mail.php` instead of `mailme.php` in your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I have edited it but still i am not getting array as a message. I am receiving an email like this.        
`userData: Array` please help me with this.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed **mail.php**? I don't see the interesting part where you do the actual mailing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will get text with 'Array' in it, to fix it change

```
foreach($_POST as $key=> $value)
{
    $message .= $key .":".$value."<br>";
}
```

to

```
foreach($_POST[userData] as $key=> $value)
{
    $message .= $key .":".$value."<br>";
}
```

(This will only work one level down in your array) or replace it with:

```
$message = print_r($_POST, true);
```

from [Store print_r result into a variable as a string or text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325067/store-print-r-result-into-a-variable-as-a-string-or-text) to show the full depth of the array