# Display variable contents with drupal_set_message

Tags: php, drupal

This is probably a dumb question, but I am new to PHP coding in Drupal. I am trying to build a Drupal 8 module.

How do I use drupal_set_message and \Drupal::logger to display variables' contents while debugging.

The following code does not work:

```
drupal_set_message('inside emailremider_mail $key');

\Drupal::logger('emailreminder')->notice('hook_mail @message %key :params');
```

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 use

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($output, true) . '</pre>');
```

and in Drupal 8 use

```
$rendered_message = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('<pre>' . print_r($output, true) . '</pre>');
drupal_set_message($rendered_message);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sam Stamport using drupal_set_message you can display content of a variable or an array.
**variable:** `drupal_set_message('inside emailremider_mail'. $key);`

**Array:** `drupal_set_message(print_r($_SESSION, true));`

\Drupal::logger can also be used to display variable

```
    // Logs a notice
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($message);
    // Logs an error
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->error($message);
```

For more information you can use the below link

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/logging-api

Hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: I've searched the web trying to find the syntax for displaying more than one variable in a single set_message, but cannot find what I need. Please give me an example. Also, please elaborate on the print_r syntax. What is $_SESSION? What does "true" do in print_r? I'm really trying to learn this stuff!

Comment: Here I have used $_SESSION variable as an array example, but in php $_SESSION  is a variable which stores the information to be used across all the pages. refer the link:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp and true is used to return the information rather than printing it.Refer the link:http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325067/store-print-r-result-into-a-variable-as-a-string-or-text.  Hope you get your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! This comment together with the previous answer answers my question.